# My delete method does not delete in the @OneToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a 1 to 1 relation of Moneda and Remesa, but when I go to delete a Moneda or a Remesa, neither deletes me, I don't get any error, simply that they are not deleted in the database. The other relationships in my tables are working fine. I don't know if it's because I have something wrong with the @OneToOne relationship

***Moneda.java***

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "moneda_sequence", sequenceName = "moneda_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "moneda_sequence")
@Column(name = "ID")
@JsonProperty("id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FECHA_INSERCION")
@JsonProperty("fechaInsercion")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaInsercion;

@Column(name = "FECHA_MODIFICACION")
@JsonProperty("fechaModificacion")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

@Column(name = "NOMBRE")
@JsonProperty("nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "ABREVIATURA")
@JsonProperty("abreviatura")
private String abreviatura;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais", nullable = true)
@JsonProperty("pais")
private Pais pais;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "moneda", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Corresponsable> corresponsables;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "moneda", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Documento> documentos;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "moneda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Remesa remesa;
```

***Remesa.java***

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "remesa_sequence", sequenceName = "remesa_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "remesa_sequence")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FECHA_INSERCION")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaInsercion;

@Column(name = "FECHA_MODIFICACION")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

private Integer tipoDoc;
private Integer entidad;
private Integer oficina;
private Integer referencia;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "remesa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Documento> documento;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "remesa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private EnvioRemesa envio_id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "moneda_id", nullable = true)
    private Moneda moneda;
```

My method to remove monedas:

```
public void getDeleteMoneda (Long moneda_id) {
        try {
            Moneda m = monedaRepo.findById(moneda_id).orElseThrow (() -> new Exception ("bad"));
            if (m! = null) {
                monedaRepo.deleteById (moneda_id); // HERE RETURN NULL DEBUGGING BUT THERE IS A MONEDA WITH THAT ID
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
}
```

The same thing happens with Remesa, the method is practically identical. Could it be a problem with the relationship of both tables?

Comment: Can you paste the entities?

Comment: I don't think so, there's nothing annotated with `@Id`

Comment: You have everything now @Andronicus